# Processing MVC combobox value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I thought it would be an easy task, but I'm struggling for a while now already.

I have `Sport` object which belongs to some `SportGroup` object.

I want to represent groups inside a combobox, and I created `SportViewModel.cs` with the following properties

```
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public Guid? SportGroupId { get;set; }
public IEnumerable<SportGroup> SportGroups {get; set; }
```

HttpGet create action

```
SportViewModel newSport = new SportViewModel();
newSport.SportGroups = new SelectList(GetAllSportGroups(), "Id", "Name");

//GetAllSportGroups() returns list of SportGroups domain objects as you can imagine.
```

My create view looks like this

```
@model Models.SportViewModel
<div>Sport group</div>
<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportGroupId, Model.SportGroups)</div>
```

Now on the controller's `httpPost` action I receive the data and try to save it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SportViewModel newSport)
{
   // if model state is valid and other checking omitted
   // session and transaction omitted
   Sport sport = new Sport();
   sport.Id = newSport.Id;
   sport.Name = newSport.Name;
   SportGroup sportGroup = session.Load<SportGroup>(SportGroupId);
   sport.SportGroups.Add(sportGroup); // here is where I'm getting an error
}
```

After submitting I'm getting these error

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
>   Referencing line  `sport.SportGroups.Add(sportGroup);`*

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: on debugging SportGroup sportGroup = session.Load<SportGroup>(SportGroupId); is properly filled with SportGroup object.

Comment: Yes OK - but how about the `.SportGroups` property on the `sport` object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// if model state is valid and other checking omitted
// session and transaction omitted
Sport sport = new Sport();

if(sport.SportGroups != null)
{
   // everything OK !
}
else
{
   // you need to instantiate the .SportGroups property!
   sport.SportGroups = new .........();
}
```

Because otherwise:

```
sport.SportGroups.Add(sportGroup); // here is where I'm getting an error
     *************
```

If this `.SportGroups` property is **NOT** properly instantiated, it will be NULL and you cannot call `.Add()` on it! You'll get that exact exception that you have.

This is typically something you would best do in the constructor of the `Sport` class - make sure that all contained collections etc. are also initalized and instantiated when you create a new object of type `Sport`

Answer (score 2):

You may not have instantiated a collection instance that is behind the SportsGroups property of the Sport class. Check it's constructor/initialization.